# unknown value <Buffer d2 f3 f0 e0 e5 e2 e0 20> when select from firebird in Node.js

Tags: database, node.js, buffer, firebird, firebird2.1

I'm new at firebird. I am trying to fetch the name from DB, but it returns:

```
<Buffer d2 f3 f0 e0 e5 e2 e0 20>
```

What does it mean? How to convert it to readable characters? Thanks in advance

```
db.query('SELECT FIRST 10 * FROM client', function(err, result) {
    // IMPORTANT: close the connection 
    console.log(result[0].name)
    db.detach();
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a Buffer object [(NodeJS docu)](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html), which is the usual return value for data, whose type is not predetermined.

To convert it to a string again, use its [`toString()`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end) method with a given encoding, e.g.:

```
var name = result[0].name.toString( 'utf8' );
```