# Buffer toString('utf8') returns ��������� after selecting from Firebird

Tags: node.js, encoding, character-encoding, buffer, firebird

I am using firebird and I select a user's data. It returns me a Buffer Object. So in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29672531/unknown-value-buffer-d2-f3-f0-e0-e5-e2-e0-20-when-select-from-firebird-in-node) they recommended doing this

```
var name = result[0].name.toString( 'utf8' );
```

So I did it and it worked, but in some rows, there are Russian chars that I do not know how to encode. And when I display them it returns ���������. How to fix it? Please community help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There solution was to use aweasome module [iconv-lite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv-lite). All I had to do is:

```
client.name = iconv.decode(client.name, 'win1251');
```

Worked like charm